# What replacement variables are available to filename in the ModelCheckpoint callback in Pytorch Lightning

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

What replacement variables `{replace_me}` are available to populate the `filename` attribute on the `ModelCallback` checkpoint in pytorch?

I want to pass the `object_id` hparam and the checkpoint version (the same as used to create the parent folder) `ver` like so:

```
pl.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filename='weights_{object_id:03}_{ver}_{epoch}-{step}')

# Saves to file:
# weights_object_id=000_ver=0_epoch=3-step=27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary metrics which have been logged and `{epoch}` and `{step}` can be used, as shown in [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.3/extensions/generated/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint.html#pytorch_lightning.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint.format_checkpoint_name).

Metrics can be logged during training (in your model class which extends `LightningModule`) like:

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    loss, logs = self.step(batch, batch_idx)
    self.log_dict(
        {f"train_{k}": v for k, v in logs.items()},
        on_step=True,
        on_epoch=True
    )
    return loss
```

If you want additional variables, which aren't logged, extend `ModelCheckpoint` and override the `format_checkpoint_name()` method.